# getjson as response in retrofit 2.0

Tags: android, json, rest, retrofit, retrofit2

iam trying to get json resopse like this but it come with improper json format how can get the string in proper format

```
Call<HashMap<Object,Object>> call = RestClient.getClient().aladata(AppUtil.getAuthKey(DashboardActivity.this),String.valueOf(mSelectedCategory.getId()), String.valueOf(mLat), String.valueOf(mLng), String.valueOf(50), String.valueOf(offset * 50));
        call.enqueue(new Callback<HashMap<Object,Object>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<HashMap<Object,Object>> call, Response<HashMap<Object,Object>> response) {
                String hashMapString=response.body().toString();
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(hashMapString);
                    String jsonstr=jsonObject.toString();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                HashMap<Object,Object> hashMap2=response.body();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<HashMap<Object,Object>> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
}
```

Comment: can ou show the response once.

Answer (score 2):

When you work with Retrofit should to use `JsonObject` instead of `JSONObject`.

Hope it helps!